# truncate a string into multiple lines

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table in mySQL that contains a field with many characters (more than 100), its a text.  I want to display my text in a `<div>`.

```
<div id="moreinformation" style="background-color:#8158BE; width:626px; height:150px; position:absolute; left:2px; top:750px">
    <label id="text" style="position:absolute;left:5px;top:2px;color:white;font: 15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
         Autre informations : 
    </label>
    <p style="position:absolute; left:5px; top:20px; color:white; font:15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
         this is an exemple of the text blablabla blablabla 
    </p>
</div>
```

The `<label>` with the id `#text` is where I want to put my text. The problem is that I don't know how to cut my text to display it in different lines and keep the correct form of the words. The main problem here is that I get an overflow all the text is written on the same line. I need your help, with CSS or jQuery, please.

Comment: My eyes are hurting from looking at those inline styles...`CSS`

Comment: Tried substitute `pre` tag for `label` tag ?

Comment: What have you tried? Perhaps if you show your attempts to solve, it would clarify what the actual issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking for, but if the problem is that the text is in the DB with line breaks and you need to display those line breaks use this in the CSS

```
label {white-space:pre-wrap;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a specific width for the `<p>` tag and your text should wrap to the next line. However, you should really consider using CSS to stylize your page, like this:

CSS

```
#moreinformation {
    background-color: #8158BE;
    width: 626px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
    top: 750px;
}
#text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 2px;
    color: white;
    font: 15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 20px;
    color: white;
    font: 15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 450px;
    display: block;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="moreinformation">
    <label id="text">Autre informations :</label>
    <p>this is an exemple of the text blablabla blablabla</p>
</div>
```